# Laravel on shared hosting with Subdomain

Tags: php, laravel, .htaccess, subdomain, hosting

I Have A shared host and i have made a laravel project and when i upload it to the host
i made a htaccess file to redirect all requests to publc/index.php
and it works very well and laravel project work good
when i create a sub domain and but some files in subdomain's folder and try to access it
i got a `500 Internal Server Error`
when i contaced the support they told me that this error because the `.htaccess` that i made
i need help to solve this problem
 this is the structure of my `public_html` folder

```
-public_html
 |-laravelproject
   |- Laravel Projct Files
 |-subdomain
   |-index.php
 |-.htaccess
```

**.htaccess file:**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^laravelproject/public
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ laravelproject/public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Do you have ssh access?

Comment: Also, shared hosting providers usually use cpanel, which usually have "Magic installers" for laravel, wordpress, ruby on rails, etc...

Comment: @Erubiel , yes I have

Comment: Is this question related to yours? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31543175/getting-a-500-internal-server-error-on-laravel-5-ubuntu-14-04 have you checked permissions?

Comment: @Erubiel, it's work very will with main domain but its not working with subdomain

Comment: You can use [laravel's routing to access your subdomain](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/routing#route-group-sub-domain-routing).

Comment: Also here's an answer where [Laravel is set up in the subdomain](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39886985/3585500) which is the opposite but might give you the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since subdomain is other installation i think you should add

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^laravelproject/public
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ laravelproject/public/$1 [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^subdomain/public
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ subdomain/public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

But im no .htaccess expert, hope it works!...