# how can i upload laravel project to shared hosting cpanel sub-domain?

Tags: laravel, subdomain

I have a domain like abc.com I have created a subdomain math.abc.com 
how to upload my project in the subdomain . I am searching in internet trying to do their way but fails . please help me .

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to upload laravel project on subdomain?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39886926/how-to-upload-laravel-project-on-subdomain)

Comment: I have also tried these step . but fails again @ShaielndraGupta

Comment: where you are failing ask here

Comment: You have to handle subdomain routes

Comment: would you please explain ho to handle subdomain routes ? @AwaisUsmani

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/routing#route-group-sub-domain-routing

Answer (score 0):

[how can i upload laravel project to shared hosting cpanel sub-domain?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53077794/how-can-i-upload-laravel-project-to-shared-hosting-cpanel-sub-domain)

You should use below link to deploy the laravel application on sub-domain.