# How to upload Laravel Project to subdomain without database?

Tags: laravel, database, upload, subdomain

I am upload project file to Sub Domain. But In web site,just project files is showing. Project is not execute. How can i resolve this problem ?

Subdomain is active.

[image]

Comment: what errors you are getting?

Comment: No error is written to the log file, the list of simple files is displayed in the browser @didenetahi

Comment: can you provide a screenshot of your displayed page?, also, can you state what are you using for subdomain hosting? ex: cPanel

Comment: I am using Cpanel. Showing file list

Comment: take a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/a/39886985/7263394

Comment: Unfortunately still web page is not execute 

Internal Server Error
The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Comment: @Bayaz is there an ```index.php``` file in your root folder? It is required

Answer (score 2):

Your hosting and configuration should have the ff:

1. Appropriate PHP version compatible to your Laravel project.
2. Composer and Laravel installed.
3. Proper web server configuration for Apache, Nginx, Litespeed, etc. This is most likely where your problem is, where you should only expose the **/public** folder as the only public directory of your page.

Answer (score 0):

I installed composer and I add `.env` file the run some commands like

```bash
php artisan key:generate
php artisan clear-compiled
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan config:clear
php artisan optimize
php artisan route:cache
```

Then resolved problem.